# Is it possible to pause my flash app on iphone by pressing home button?

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm quite new to Flash. So here's my problem: I've created my app and it works great. But when I press home button on my iphone, my app minimizes and when I open it from multitasking apps, it simply restarts. Is it possible to freeze or pause the game instead of stop? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you didn't specify that your app could multitask.  I wonder, do flash apps include a plist?

Answer (score 0):

By default the application should be eligible for the 'freeze-drying' iOS4+ functionality that resumes an app from the last place it left off. That may require a setting to be adjusted in your app descriptor (UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend should be false).

If you simply need to save data when the application is quitting, you can listen for Event.EXITING on the NativeApplication:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, onExit);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But this link solved my problem: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/868170

Comment: The general consensus aside from the Java error in that thread is that you need to set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to false... O.o

Comment: Tegeril: Can you confirm that Event.Exiting Still works? When I press the home button, I get the deactivate but no exit.

Comment: I don't have anything at the moment that is relying on that code. But if you're not getting Event.EXITING with UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend set to true upon hitting the home button, then something may well have changed.